# illegal start of expression error, working with methods

Tags: methods, expression

So I keep getting illegal start of expression errors around line 30 when trying to run my DiceGame program which is practice with methods. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DiceGame
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final int RANGE = 6; 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userGuess = input.next();
        int throwResult = throw2Dice(RANGE); 
        int programGuess = throw2Dice(RANGE);


        int userError = Math.abs(throwResult - userGuess);
        int programError = Math.abs(throwResult - programGuess); 
        boolean userWins = false; 
        if(userError < programError)
        {
            userWins = true; 
        {
        System.out.println("Your guess was: " + userGuess + " the program's guess was: " + programGuess + " and the result was: " + throwResult); 
        if(userWins == false)
            System.out.println("Program Wins!!!");
        else
            System.out.println("User Wins!!!"); 
    }


    public static int throw2Dice(int r)
    { 
        int number1 = (Math.random() * r + 1);
        int number2 = (Math.random() * r + 1);
        int sum = number1 + number2; 
        return sum; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(userError < programError)
{
    userWins = true; 
{
```

You have two open braces instead of an open brace and a close brace.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. That little mistake had me so frustrated.